# Unknown SQL server host error in phpMyAdmin after switching php versions in WAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I've installed Wamp Server 2.2, which includes php 5.3.13, Apache 2.2.22 and MySQL 5.5.24. Then I installed php 5.2.4 using the WampServer2-PHP524.exe extension found [here on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/).

When I switch to php 5.2.4 I get an error in phpMyAdmin telling me "#2005 - Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3307' (11001)" (I have XAMPP installed also at this point, so MySQL is set up on port 3307 for the WAMP install.)

I've tried a few different things based on various responses to similar problems:

Based on this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/304901/wamp-installation-multiple-php-version-issues), I copied php.ini from the php 5.2.4 directory into the Apache bin directory.

I tried changing the php.ini setting for `mysql.default_port` from blank to my port 3307

My phpMyAdmin config file has these settings:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost:3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = _private_;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

I've double checked `my.ini` to make sure my port settings are correct. It all works with php 5.3.13, so I really don't think it's anything to do with an errant port setting, though.

I tried changing the phpMyAdmin alias file to this, per a response to another question that I can't find now:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've also verified that that directory is the correct directory for phpMyAdmin.

I've compared the php.ini file between 5.2.4 and 5.3.13 and I don't really see any differences between the two as far as how MySQL is set up.

Does php 5.2.4 require a different version or Apache and/or MySQL?

I'm trying to get this working so that I can ensure my WordPress plugins are compatible with WordPress's minimum requirements.

Oh, and, I doubt it needs to be said, but I did restart all services between each change.

---

This is the MySQL log.

```
140621  9:52:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140621  9:52:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140621  9:52:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140621  9:52:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140621  9:52:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140621  9:52:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140621  9:52:18 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140621  9:52:18  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140621  9:52:19 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
140621  9:52:19 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3307
140621  9:52:19 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
140621  9:52:19 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140621  9:52:19 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140621  9:52:19 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140621  9:52:19 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3307  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: I don't understand: php 5.2.4 would fit the *minimum* reqs, but php 5.3.13 would not? Is there some extension in the former which isn't available in the later?

Comment: @didierc WordPress requires at least 5.2.4 and for the plugin to be fully compatible with WordPress it needs to be able to run on a server running 5.2.4.  There are features in [5.3 that are not available in 5.2](http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration53.new-features.php), so I feel it would be good to have a server running 5.2.4 for WordPress development, so that I don't accidentally write something incompatible.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered running a linux vm with the right setup?

Comment: Well, I used to use linux, but my new computer has windows 8, which has created a whole lot of problems as far as that is concerned. While I could setup virtualbox with a linux vm, it's not something I really want to do, mostly because this computer is crazy slow (seriously, never buy a Sony Vaio computer). I would rather get this working on windows. If I have to go the linux route I will. But I would like to figure out why WAMP Server isn't working right now.

Comment: Of course, I understand.

Comment: Have you checked to wamp logs? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713001/where-can-i-find-the-wamp-error-log)

Comment: @didierc I don't see anything strange in the log, but I'm not at all an expert in this area. I posted it to the question just in case. It's binding to 0.0.0.0, which I believe is correct.

Comment: Is it only a problem with phpmyadmin, or any other php script fail at opening a mysql connection?

Comment: @didierc Scripts work, it is just phpMyAdmin. I suppose I can work without phpMyAdmin, but I am a visual person and it is nice to see it all there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Host and Port are separate variables, you need to remove the port from the host variable.

Change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307';
```

to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

[From here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Weird that it worked fine with php 5.3.13.